# Cause Symfony validation constraint annotations to cascade

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I have a class called `NamedAdapter` that has some properties. These properties are being fed by a Symfony form, and they have some validation constraints listed above them as annotations. When the properties that reside directly within the `NamedAdapter` class are not what is desired, they rightly cause one or more `ConstraintViolation` complaints to appear during form validation.

The problem is that `NamedAdapter` and its related form type also contain references to compound fields that are their own form types, and that have other, smaller classes associated with them. For simplicity, we'll call those classes `SmallerClassOne` and `SmallerClassTwo`.

These other, smaller classes also have annotations that specify validation desires, but when those annotations are disobeyed, no complaint shows up.

I have tried setting `error_bubbling` to true but, as I expected, this did not cause a change in behavior. (If I understand that option correctly, it has more to do with *how* errors are displayed, rather than *whether* they're displayed.)

**Is there some sort of class-wide annotation that I should be applying to the class definitions of the smaller component classes (`SmallerClassOne` and `SmallerClassTwo`) in order to get their validation problems to show up during form validation? If so, what is it?**

EDITS:

-- The form types are nested within one another.

-- The `@Assert\Valid()` annotation is already present above the fields that contain `SmallerClassOne` and `SmallerClassTwo` in the top-level class.

-- Here is a slightly modified copy of the code that's being used. Submitting the string "bob" as the latitude does not induce a `ConstraintViolation`.

```
<?php

class NamedAdapter implements SomeInterface
{
    /** @Assert\Valid */
    private ?SmallerClassOne $mySmallerObject = null;


    /** @Assert\Valid */
    private ?SmallerClassTwo $myOtherSmallerObject = null;

    ...

}

class SmallerClassOne
{
     /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.")
     */
    private ?float $latitude;

    ....
}

class SmallerClassTwo
{
     /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}.")
     */
    private ?float $latitude;

    ....
}
```

Comment: [`Valid`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)?

Comment: Are the forms nested in each other or are they completely independent? Can you show the code you nest the forms?

Comment: Thanks guys. I have added edits to the bottom of the question in response to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `$latitude` and `$longitude` fields were not being set directly via setters for those fields, but through a compound `setCoordinates()` method. So I had to use `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` at the tops of `SmallerClassOne` and `SmallerClassTwo`, then create something like the following farther down:

```
/** @Assert\Callback(methods={"setCoordinates"}) */
public function assertValidLatitude(ExecutionContextInterface $context): void
{
    if (!is_float($this->latitude)) {
        $context
            ->buildViolation('latitude must be a float')
            ->atPath('my.property.path')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

That seems to have done the trick.

EDIT: This did not actually work, which makes sense, as the property I was validating had not been populated yet. I will leave this answer up, though, in case it leads someone to a useful piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

In the Twig you can display errors like this:

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.vars.errors %}
        <li class="text-danger">{{error.message}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>  
{% endif %}
```